# error while deploying the sitecore jss react app

Tags: sitecore-jss

The sitecore instance is of SXA and it contains multiple domains under single jss tenant.
The deploy was for one single domain under the tenant

I was trying to create a react app, when i deploy to sitecore jss i am facing this error!

PS C:\Users\rohith\Downloads\reactapp> jss deploy:reactapp --acceptCertificate thumbprint

> npm run deploy:reactapp -- --acceptCertificate thumbprint
> jss deploy app --destination C:\inetpub\wwwroot\reactappsc.dev.local\dist\reactapp "--acceptCertificate" "thumbprint"

JSS is creating a manifest for intranet to ./sitecore/manifest...
Cleaning path ./sitecore/manifest...
Cleaned:
C:\Users\rohith\Downloads\reactapp\sitecore\manifest\sitecore-import.json
Enabling Babel 7 transpilation for the manifest...
path or pattern './sitecore/pipelines/**/*.patch.js' did not match any files.
path or pattern './sitecore/pipelines/**/*.patch.ts' did not match any files.
Manifest has been generated and written to ./sitecore/manifest/sitecore-import.json
JSS is manifest packaging intranet to ./sitecore/package...
Adding sitecore-import.json
Wrote sitecore\package\reactapp.1654692023286.manifest.zip
Sending package sitecore\package\intranet.1654692023286.manifest.zip to https://reactappsc.dev.local/sitecore/api/jss/import...
Sitecore has accepted import task JSSImport-reactapp-6:10:23 PM
Job started: JSSImport-reactapp
Importing reactapp as sitecore\admin
Import database is master
VerifyAppConfiguration - Import templates path was not set for app reactapp, ensure 'templatesPath' attribute is configured.

Import is complete.

IMPORT ERROR(S) OCCURRED!
VerifyAppConfiguration - Import templates path was not set for app reactapp, ensure 'templatesPath' attribute is configured.

***any help on this? how to resolve this error***

Comment: Try posting it on Sitecore stack exchange https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would assume you confirmed the 'templatesPath' was existing. An example is located here in your project "\App_Config\Sitecore\JavaScriptServices\Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ExampleApp.config.example". Also check for blocked files and folder access to make sure the service can access the location